# Android AES in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, encryption, libgdx, aes

I am trying to encrypt something using AES and then save. The problem is that its working on my computer, but not on android. What is the problem?

This is main AES class:

```
public class AESUtils {

    public static byte[] encrypt(SecretKeySpec skeySpec, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(SecretKeySpec skeySpec, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static SecretKeySpec getKey(String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed(key.getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        return new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
    }
}
```

FileSaveClass:

```
public class FileUtils {

    public static void save(FileHandle file, byte[] bytes) {
        file.writeBytes(bytes, false);
    }

    public static byte[] load(FileHandle file) {
        return file.readBytes();
    }
}
```

And it's that i am trying to do:

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = AESUtils.getKey("Any key");

// if file not exist - create new, else open it, add any symbol and save it again

if (!fileHandle.exists()) {
    byte[] encodedBytes = AESUtils.encrypt(skeySpec, text.getBytes());
    SaveUtils.save(fileHandle, encodedBytes);
} else {
    byte[] clearBytes = AESUtils.decrypt(skeySpec, SaveUtils.load(fileHandle));
    text = new String(clearBytes);
    text += "1";

    byte[] encodedBytes = AESUtils.encrypt(skeySpec, text.getBytes());
    SaveUtils.save(fileHandle, encodedBytes);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: "*its working on my computer, but not on android*" what *does* it do on android? Does it throw an exception? Does it hang? Does it not encrypt? please be specific. Many thanks.

Comment: On android logcat give not any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your device may have an API version greater than or equal to 17 (Jelly Bean). Changing the static method getKey(String key) to the following code may solve the problem:

```
public static SecretKeySpec getKey(String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    final int JELLY_BEAN_4_2 = 17;
    SecureRandom sr = null;

    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android) {
       if (Gdx.app.getVersion() >=  JELLY_BEAN_4_2) {
          sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
       } else {
          sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
       }
    } else if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.iOS) {
       sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
    } else {
       sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    }

    sr.setSeed(key.getBytes());

    kg.init(128, sr);
    return new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
}
```